# Сериализация для разных абстрактных классов с множеством наследников

Tags: c++, ооп, сериализация

Как записать и прочесть наследников разных абстрактных классов?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

// ============================================================================
//  Bases
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Base1 {
public:
    virtual void func1() = 0;
};
class Base2 {
public:
    virtual void func2() = 0;
};
class Base3 {
public:
    virtual void func3() = 0;
};

// ============================================================================
//  Derived
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Derived11 : public Base1 {
public:
    void func1() override {
        std::cout << 11 << std::endl;
    }
};
class Derived12 : public Base1 {
public:
    void func1() override {
        std::cout << 12 << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived21 : public Base2 {
public:
    void func2() override {
        std::cout << 21 << std::endl;
    }
};
class Derived22 : public Base2 {
public:
    void func2() override {
        std::cout << 22 << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived31 : public Base3 {
public:
    void func3() override {
        std::cout << 31 << std::endl;
    }
};
class Derived32 : public Base3 {
public:
    void func3() override {
        std::cout << 32 << std::endl;
    }
};

// ============================================================================
//  Serialization
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename _Ty>
void Write(std::ostream& Stream, _Ty Container) {
    size_t Size = Container.size();
    Stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&Size), sizeof(Size));

    if (Size > 0)
        for (auto Value : Container)
            Stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&Value), sizeof(Value));
}
template <typename _Ty>
void Read(std::istream& Stream, _Ty& Container) {
    size_t Size;
    Stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Size), sizeof(Size));

    Container.clear();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Size; ++i) {
        typename _Ty::value_type Value = { }; // Value - is nullptr
        Stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Value), sizeof(Value));
        Container.push_back(Value);
    }
}

// ============================================================================
//  Main
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
    std::vector<Base1*> Vector1;
    Vector1.push_back(new Derived11);
    Vector1.push_back(new Derived12);

    std::vector<Base2*> Vector2;
    Vector2.push_back(new Derived21);
    Vector2.push_back(new Derived22);

    std::vector<Base3*> Vector3;
    Vector3.push_back(new Derived31);
    Vector3.push_back(new Derived32);

    // Write
    std::fstream File("file.a", std::ios::out);
    assert(File.is_open());
    Write(File, Vector1);
    Write(File, Vector2);
    Write(File, Vector3);
    File.close();

// 
//  ...
// 

    // Read
    File.open("file.a", std::ios::in);
    assert(File.is_open());
    Read(File, Vector1);
    Read(File, Vector2);
    Read(File, Vector3);
    File.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: При чтении из файла невозможно угадать тип объекта. Сначала нужно записать в файл его код. Потом можно писать весь объект. И написать свой каталог объектов `enum Types{..,T22 = 22,..};` `virtual Types Type(){return T22;}`

Comment: При записывании объекта нужно писать не указатель, а сам объект с фактическими его виртуальными размерами. То-есть в функции `Write` нужен `switch(типа объекта)` дальше приведение к нужному указателю и т.д.

Comment: я код сериализации вырвал из своего проекта, если я сделаю то, что написали вы, то мне при добавлении новых наследников придется постоянно изменять 
функцию Read в коде сериализации, добавляя в switch новые типы, есть ли другой способ решить эту проблему?

Comment: Делаем опять статическую функцию `static size_t SizeOf(int code);` для считывания из файла. А также ф-ию **создания** объекта `static Base * New(int code);` в которой с помощью опять `switch(code)` делаем новый объект `new Type;`. Эту функцию `Read` уже можно не трогать. Всё и сразу я вам не напишу.

Comment: проблема в том, что базовый класс абстрактный, а для того чтобы вызвать метод для создания объекта, надо создать объект абстрактного класса, чего сделать невозможно

Comment: функция `New` - статическая и ей не нужен экземпляр объекта.

Comment: в моем оригинальном коде, функция **Read** для классов работает только с наследниками **ISerialization**
метод `New` в классе **ISerialization** я в реализовал следующим образом 

`virtual ISerialization* NewCallback(UINT Type) = 0;` 

`static ISerialization* New(void* pThis, UINT Type) {
 return ((ISerialization*)pThis)->NewCallback(Type);
}`